# coudnt use logback because of log4j

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

Hi i have problems with logback and slf4j, im writing simple app that later is packaging in jar and i want to add there logging using logback

im using:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>${c3p0.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>${commons.pool.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>${ehcache.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>${gson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>${jedis.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

in Main i have:

```
LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
configurator.setContext(loggerContext);
configurator.doConfigure(logbackFile)
```

it used for load logback.xml configuration outside of jar file

The funniest thing is that this program is working on local machine (Windows) (reading logback.xml, create file, write to file) but when i upload it to remote  server (linux) i have strange error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext
```

the question is why he want to cast ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext from org.slf4j.impl.**Log4jLoggerFactory**??

I dont have anywhere any lib of log4j... i mean i dont have it on entire machine

one additional info:
on Windows i have Java from Oracle and on Linux i have openjdk - it can be a problem?

//=================dependency tree

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-client:jar:5.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.fusesource.hawtbuf:hawtbuf:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.2-pre6:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] +- postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.1-901.jdbc4:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] +- redis.clients:jedis:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
```

Comment: Because of you try to get LoggerFactory and cast it to LoggerContext: 
`LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();`

Comment: Can you provide a whole dependency tree of your application? It seems you have slf4j-log4j somewhere on your classpath. That is the log4j binding.

Comment: updated, i was looking at dependency tree and i doesnt see anything with log4j

Comment: @TomaszCy-man Please post the output of `mvn dependency:tree` (run in the main project)

Comment: Either post the result of mvn dependency:tree or at least provide the versions of your dependencies as well. If you are *certain* there is no org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j dependency in your deployment, check the (class)path of your application on the linux machine. That org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory class *has* to come from somewhere.

Comment: like i said i search log4j.jar on entire linux machine and i didnt find it
when i use echo $CLASSPATH on linux it return me nothing

i added all dependency tree

Comment: That is because it's not coming from a *log4j.jar*. **This** is the one you should be looking for: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.slf4j%7Cslf4j-log4j12%7C1.7.12%7Cjar

Comment: and it let me use logback? I think it is for binding slf4j and log4j. Maybe ill say one more, when i try to load logback config automatic (from jar) i have: 
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.pro.Main).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Comment: Whats the full package name of Import for LogContext in your java class ?

Comment: No, that file binds slf4j to log4j, which **prevents** you from using logback! That is why you should be looking for it and eliminating it. Aaand... that additional info **might have been useful at the start** because it clearly states that slf4j is using a log4j binding, which you do not want. There **is** one form or another of slf4j-log4j12.jar on your classpath!

Comment: imports in class: import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator;
import ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

Comment: There is one form or another of slf4j-log4j12.jar on your classpath! -- but i cant find anything like that, i search anything thats matching *log4j.jar *log4j12.jar and i found nothing :(

Comment: You'll need another * in front of the .jar to capture the different versions. The file name is something like slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar, as seen here: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.slf4j%7Cslf4j-log4j12%7C1.7.12%7Cjar

Comment: find / -name \*log4j*.jar ---- it return nothing

Comment: Found a fix for this?

Comment: Can you share the complete output of `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: i cant, i don`t have that project and enviroment already...

Answer (score 3):

Due to an already existing dependency of SLF4J in your project or in some other inherited project, there might be conflicts during runtime. Adding an exclusion to my `POM` file worked for me:

```
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
```

Comment: Where to add this exclusions? in logback-classic or in compiler plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Trying taking out the dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

This Dependency is included in

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

As you see in the logback-classic pom file - http://central.maven.org/maven2/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/logback-classic-1.1.3.pom

Also make sure that when you initialize your logger that it is modeled after

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(ClassName.class)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what it says here: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/1205 , there is a race condition with initializing the libraries. I was having a similar problem where my program worked fine on NetBeans, but didn't work in a gnome terminal. A race condition explains the inconsistent behavior common in multiple cases. I don't fully understand why this happens, but there is a workaround here for a specific case: https://gist.github.com/mbknor/34944ea4589a5fc6974c .  This example is from that link, it may not be applicable to the specific case mentioned above but can probably be adapted for specific cases fairly easily if you understand what's going on.

```
static {
        System.out.println("Waiting for slf4j to finish initialization");
        while ( LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory() instanceof SubstituteLoggerFactory){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to switch the logger in my controller from:

```
private static final Logger log = LogbackUtil.getLogger( MyController.class );
```

to

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger( MyController.class );
```